# How much gold does it take to unlock all crafting recipes?

Tags: diablo-iii

How much gold does it take to level up each crafting NPC?

If I want to unlock all recipes, how much gold will it cost me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this post need an update for anyone looking for up-to-date information. With the patch 1.0.3, the upgrading cost of the Blacksmith as been greatly reduced.
That said, the Blacksmith tier unlock costs break down like this, still actual for 1.0.7 and 1.0.8:

Normals tiers

- free
- 5,000 gold
- 6,000 gold
- 10,000 gold

Nightmare tiers

- 12,000 gold + 2 pages of blacksmithing
- 20,000 gold + 6 pages of blacksmithing

Hell tiers

- 22,000 gold + 4 pages of blacksmithing + 2 tomes of blacksmithing
- 30,000 gold + 6 tomes of blacksmithing

Inferno tiers

- 28,000 gold + 4 tomes of blacksmithing + 2 tomes of secrets
- 40,000 gold + 9 tomes of secrets

This puts maxing the blacksmith at a total of 173,000 gold and some cheap books.
Since there is not modification for the jeweler, to maximize both artisans, you need:

- 313,000 gold
- 12 pages of blacksmithing
- 20 pages of jewelcrafting
- 12 tomes of blacksmithing
- 20 tomes of jewelcrafting
- 51 tomes of secrets

Answer (score 5):

Individual recipe level costs can be found within the links for each Artisan.

- [Blacksmith](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/progression/#level=1): 593,000 gold
- [Jeweler](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/progression/#level=1): 140,000 gold

So in total, 733,000 gold is required to unlock all the recipes.