# How much do I need to invest into the artisan to fully upgrade?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much gold does it take to unlock all crafting recipes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66112/how-much-gold-does-it-take-to-unlock-all-crafting-recipes)

How much of my precious, precious gold do I need to invest to *fully* upgrade the Artisan...?