# What is the total cost of leveling up your crafters?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much gold does it take to unlock all crafting recipes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66112/how-much-gold-does-it-take-to-unlock-all-crafting-recipes)

How many Pages, Tomes, Books of Secret and Gold is required to completely max out the Jewelcrafter and Blacksmith?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

[Blacksmith Leveling Guide](http://www.diablo3professions.com/blacksmith-artisan-overview/diablo-3-blacksmith-leveling-guide/)

**Total Cost of Blacksmith:**

- 645,000 gold
- 50 Page of Blacksmithing
- 50 Tome of Blacksmithing
- 45 Tome of Secrets

[Jeweler Leveling Guide](http://www.diablo3professions.com/jeweler-artisan-overview/diablo-3-jeweler-leveling-guide/)

**Total Cost of Jeweler:**

- 130,000 gold
- 10 Page of Jewelcrafting (Nightmare)
- 20 Tome of Jewelcrafting (Hell)
- 40 Tome of Secrets (Inferno)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

### You can read all the [official guide](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/)

### Blacksmith

**Apprentice**
Cost: 10000 gold
5 steps, 2000 gold each

**Journeyman**
Cost: 20000 gold
5 steps, 4000 gold each

**Adept**
Cost: 30000 gold
5 steps, 6000 gold each

**Master**
Cost: 35000 gold and 5 pages of Blacksmithing
5 steps, 7000 gold each but the final step requires 5 Pages of Blacksmithing

**Grandmaster**
Cost: 75000 gold and 25 pages of Blacksmithing
5 steps, 15000 gold and 5 pages of Blacksmithing each

**Illustrious**
Cost: 75000 gold, 20 pages of Blacksmithing, 5 Tomes of Blacksmithing
5 steps, 15000 gold and 5 pages of Blacksmithing each; final step requires 5 Tomes of Blacksmithing instead of Pages of Blacksmithing

**Magnificent**
Cost: 100,000 gold, 25 Tomes of Blacksmithing
5 steps, each costing 20,000 gold and 5 Tomes of Blacksmithing

**Resplendent**
Cost: 100,000 gold, 20 Tomes of Blacksmithing and 5 Tomes of Secrets
5 steps, each costing 20,000 gold and 5 Tomes of Blacksmithing,
the last step requires 5 Tomes of Secrets instead of Tomes of Blacksmithing.

**Glorious**
Cost: 200,000 gold, 25 Tomes of Secrets
5 steps, each one costing 40,000 gold and 25 Tomes of Secrets

**Exalted**
No cost; as soon as you hit level 10 you are finished.

### Jeweler

**Apprentice**

**Journeyman**
Level up: 5000 gold.

**Adept**
Level up: 5000 gold.

**Master**
Level up: 10,000 gold and 10 Page of Jewelcrafting

**Grandmaster**
Level up: 10,000 gold and 10 Page of Jewelcrafting

**Illustrious**
Level up: 10,000 gold and 10 Tome of Jewelcrafting

**Magnificent**
Level up: 10,000 gold and 10 Tome of Jewelcrafting

**Resplendent**
Level up: 20,000 gold and 10 Tome of Secrets

**Glorious**
Level up: 20,000gold and 10 Tome of Secrets

**Exalted**
Level up: 40,000 gold and 20 Tome of Secrets