# Can my Artisans reach level 5 in normal difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

In order to level up the Artisans to level 5, pages of jewelcrafting and pages of blacksmithing are needed, which are dropped only on nightmare difficulty. But the AH sells them, can I buy them from the AH and upgrade my Artisans using them before any of my characters reach nightmare difficulty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much gold does it take to unlock all crafting recipes?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66112/how-much-gold-does-it-take-to-unlock-all-crafting-recipes)

Comment: @Wipqozn, this question touches on a subject that wasn't addressed by that question, nor by its answers.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I don't see how this could be a duplicate.

Comment: IlyaMelamed @pants I see your point. Raven's answer implies this, but doesn't state it directly. Considering the only relation between the two is RAven's answer, then I agree this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: This whole question is out of date. AH doesnt exist

Comment: question is about content that does not exist inside diablo 3 anymore. at least, not on any legal server. nightmare difficulty and auction house have been removed, while the method for upgrading the artisans has also changed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can, I've done so myself.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: Is it possible to give more description, possibly link to an outside source?

Comment: Not sure about more description. The question is pretty straight forward, I'm not sure how I could elaborate the answer without simply repeating what has already been said in the question, it's really a yes or no question.  I can try and find an outside source though.

Comment: Couldn't find any outside source but added images that should prove that my answer is correct. These are examples of my blacksmith having been trained using pages and proof that my character is in act 2 without any higher difficulty available than normal. Thus proving I can't obtain artisan pages myself.