# Do you have to make it all the way to inferno to level the jeweler up completely?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much gold does it take to unlock all crafting recipes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66112/how-much-gold-does-it-take-to-unlock-all-crafting-recipes)

I appologize if this has already been covered, but I couldn't find the information anywhere.

I just made it to Nightmare on my Wizard, and noticed that I needed to collect crafting pages to level up the Jewel Crafter Covetious Shen.  Are there pages in each difficulty, or will I be able to finish leveling him up in Nightmare?

Also, if each difficulty setting has its own pages, can you buy them off the AH to gain access to the higher level gems early on?

Thanks!

Comment: And this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69498/can-my-artisans-reach-level-5-in-normal-difficulty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the commodities AH is down, so I think you cannot buy pages off AH.

You're correct, you can't upgrade the jeweler completely from the pages found in NM.

- Nightmare: Pages of Jewelcrafting
- Hell: Tome of Jewelcrafting
- Inferno: Tome of Secrets (common to jeweler & blacksmith?)

I know NM & Hell are pages and tomes; unsure about Inferno but you need them from all 3 difficulties to fully upgrade either jeweler or blacksmith.

Comment: The Tome of Secrets' are in fact shared between both professions.